# How to change an Info.plist flag based on the TARGET_OS?

Tags: xcode, build, run-script, info-plist, uikitformac

I'm attempting to migrate my iOS app to support builds for the `UIKitForMac` target (project **Catalyst!**).

I'm attempting to change an `Info.plist` flag based on the `TARGET_OS`, but I'm not sure how can I detect the target OS from a build phase's run script. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
echo "[DEBUG-PRINT] ---> Update flag"
if [ ${TARGET_OS_UIKITFOTMAC} ]; then
echo "[DEBUG-PRINT] ---> IF succeeded"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace YES" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a pre-action run script to my scheme:

```
#!/bin/sh
INFO_PLIST="$INFOPLIST_FILE"
RAW_BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "$INFO_PLIST")
if [[ $OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS == *"-D TARGET_OS_UIKITFORMAC"* ]] && [[ $RAW_BUNDLE_ID != uikitformac* ]]; then
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier uikitformac.$RAW_BUNDLE_ID" "$INFO_PLIST"
elif [[ $OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS != *"-D TARGET_OS_UIKITFORMAC"* ]] && [[ $RAW_BUNDLE_ID == uikitformac* ]]; then
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier ${RAW_BUNDLE_ID#'uikitformac.'}" "$INFO_PLIST"
fi
```